# different search results when using SharePoint default search vs using object model

Tags: sharepoint-server, enterprise-search

I am facing an issue in SharePoint search, when I am using SharePoint default UI to search, it is showing different set of results and when I am searching using search object model, it is showing a different set of results. I am using the below code:

```
SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy = (SearchServiceApplicationProxy)SearchServiceApplicationProxy.GetProxy(SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site));
KeywordQuery query = new KeywordQuery(proxy);

query.ResultsProvider = Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Query.SearchProvider.Default;
query.QueryText = queryText;
```

Comment: What are the differences? Make sure to only look at the "Relevant Resuls" returned from your KQL above

Comment: difference in items in result, it seems both results are coming from different sources. In CA, there are multiple content sources.

Comment: You might want to check if the any permission change. It worth to do full crawl and see if the search results are now consistent

Comment: At Site level, There are three scopes 1. All Sites 2. People 3. MyCustomScope. when i am using search object model, it is showing data from 'All Sites' scope but my requirement is to show resulrs from 'MyCustomSearch' scope. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code helped me

```
ServerContext context = ServerContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
FullTextSqlQuery qrySearch = new FullTextSqlQuery(context);
//Specifies the results set containing the main search results from the content index matching the search query.
qrySearch.ResultTypes = ResultType.RelevantResults;
qrySearch.EnableStemming = true;
qrySearch.TrimDuplicates = false;
qrySearch.QueryText = "SELECT SubCategory,ReferenceName,DocType,MainCategory,URL,Title, HitHighlightedSummary FROM SCOPE() where \"scope\"='<Name of Scope Here>' And FREETEXT(*,'" + queryText + "')";
ResultTableCollection results = qrySearch.Execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case its SharePoint 2013: I would suggest to compare the results with the awesome Search Query Tool (https://sp2013searchtool.codeplex.com/) - there you can impersonate as different users, target scopes and more.